# Aws::Errors::MissingCredentialsError (unable to sign request without credentials set) - Beanstalk, security via IAM Roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam, amazon-ses

My setup:

- Rails 5.2 application
- Amazon SES, using [aws-sdk-rails](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-rails/tree/v2.1.0) gem

  - authenticated with IAM roles (not access key & secret)
- Elastic Beanstalk

I have just switched my Elastic Beanstalk environment from Amazon Linux AMI (v1) to a new environment with Amazon Linux 2 (v2). I have kept my configuration as identical as possible to maintain application behaviour, although when sending emails with my Rails app, powered by Amazon Simple Email Service (SES), I get the following error:

```
Aws::Errors::MissingCredentialsError (unable to sign request without credentials set)
```

The documentation here describes a number of methods to authenticate the AWS SDK, and I'm using the "Setting Credentials Using IAM" approach:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/developer-guide/setup-config.html

I'm using the Rails gem for AWS SES email sending here:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-rails/tree/v2.1.0
and given I'm using IAM roles, I only need to set the region when initializing the mailer:

```
Aws::Rails.add_action_mailer_delivery_method(:aws_sdk, region: "us-west-2")
```

Both my old v1 EB environment and my new v2 EB environment create EC2 instances with the same role, i.e the `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role`, and I can see that it has the same Security Policy attached to it that I set up a while back called "MySendEmailPolicy". And this policy looks like it gives the right permissions access to send emails:
[image]

I can't think of any other reason why AWS would say my credentials are now failing. Any thoughts? Perhaps there's something different about Amazon Linux 2?

Comment: AL2 has things that will break previous deploys.  I have just gone through deploying this morning after screaming at my poor innocent monitor for hours yesterday.  

It is not clear from your post whether this will apply, but if anything needs access to environment variables after deploy, they are not available in the environment by default.  You can add them like this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-configuration-methods-after.html  

Good luck!

Comment: @DrewJohnston I don't *think* that would be the cause because if environment variables weren't correct at app start-up time, then 100's of things would be breaking. But it's just SES that is. Having said that, I have noticed that I used to be able to `eb ssh`, then `sudo -i`, then `cd /var/app/current` then `bin/rails console`, but it fails due to no ENV vars being set (e.g. critical ones like `RACK_ENV=production`). Running this fixes it for that case though: `export $(cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env | xargs)`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an IAM-roles solution to the problem, but a work-around I'm using which gets emails working at least for now.

I'm simply using my own AWS CLI credentials here, which I've added as environment variables via the Elastic Beanstalk web console:

```
creds = Aws::Credentials.new(ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"], ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"])
Aws::Rails.add_action_mailer_delivery_method(:aws_sdk, credentials: creds, region: "us-west-2")
```

After deploying above, I got this error: `Aws::SES::Errors::AccessDenied (User 'arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:user/<userName>' is not authorized to perform 'ses:SendRawEmail' on resource 'arn:aws:ses:us-west-2:XXXXXXXXXXXX:identity/<example.com>')`, but that was resolved by attaching my "MySendEmailPolicy" policy to my IAM user directly.

Any suggestions on the IAM-roles solution though would be welcome.